# Angularjs Directive: How to update ng-class in template after change in attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, directive, ng-class

I have the following directive:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.navbar')
    .directive('myItem', myItem);

  function myItem() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        href: '@'
      },
      template : 
        '<li ng-class="{\'active\' : scope.active}"><a href="{{href}}" ng-transclude></a></li>',
      link : link
    };
    return directive;

    /////////////////

    function link(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        scope.active = ('isActive' in attr);
        console.log("scope active: " + scope.active);
      })
    }
  }

})();
```

I want the `ng-class` expression in the template code to add the `active` class if there is an `is-active` attribute in the html, for instance...

```
<my-item>Item 1</my-item>
<my-item is-active>Item 2</my-item>
```

...would be the html and the `Item 2` menu item would be activated. As you can see I've implemented a `link` function where I'm trying to evaluate whether there is an attribute called `is-active`. If this exists then I'm setting a scope variable called `scope.active`. As far as the `ng-class` in the template can discern, however, this scope variable always remains undefined.

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `scope` prefix, evaluation context is `scope` object itself:

```
template: '<li ng-class="{active: active}"><a href="{{href}}" ng-transclude></a></li>',
```

You also don't need `$watch` just set `scope.active = 'isActive' in attr;` in link function.

Comment: Thankyou! For both suggestions. I added the $watch to see if that fixed my initial attempt.